# jQuery solid animation speed (background % position)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made an image div with 9 divs (who have a `mouseenter` function) on it. If you hover over one div the background image's position animates (it's all based on percentage). I want it all to move with the same speed, but I can't get it to work, the speed is always different.

Any solutions, suggestions or tips?

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3kgv5/)

Comment: Your animations are based on percentage. And your image is not a square image (960x380). In your code, you want the animations to be done in 2500 milliseconds. Vertical and horizontal path lengths are not equal, so the speed will differ when moving up-down or left-right.

Comment: @user3280126 I noticed that, so I'm wondering: How can I make it so the speed stays the same?

Comment: If your image size is fixed, you can calculate each div's seconds by seeing with your eyes. If it's not fixed, static second assignment will nearly always fail, it will be much more complicated.